# How to assign the first user referer (source / medium) to an event with GTM and GA?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to solve the following issue.

I have "submit form" events in GA (google analytics) and the thing I need to do is to understand what was the first source and medium (from first session) of those events. The main goal is to know what campaigns or sources initiate "submit form" event that happens after a couple of monthes. I use Tag Manager + Universal analytics only so I hope to make implementation through them.

I see next solutions:

Create custom dimension and save first cookie referral. How to do it?
Somehow do it with user ID and Client ID
Somehow do it through ecommerce tracking
It's important that I can't modify html code so we are going to use GTM and GA only. Please assist. Pretty sure that I'm not alone who is struggling with such problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a library from sbjs.rocks. It can store source data in cookies and you can use GTM to add the library to your website.

In GTM using first-party cookie variable you can get source data from cookies and use it as a custom dimension or one of event fields.

Comment: first-party cookie variable - I completely forgot about that! Thanks a lot. But I'm not sure about sbjs.rocks and how can I use it and what should I add to my website

Comment: You need to host the library somewhere and add it to your site using Custom HTML tag. Read through the description of library to get more info how to get first users' source.

Comment: I've already read but I don't understand how to connect first-party variable with the data (source) that I'm going to store in sbjs.rocks and push all this stuff with event.. My programming skills are on beginners level.

Comment: The library stores source data in cookies so you can pull that data using first-party cookie variables and use it in your tags.

Comment: Thanks! I've already solved the issue in another way. Yo can send back Client ID to GA as custom dimension and than build custom report with hierarchy ClientID--Timestamp--Source and choose first date to see first referer. You can find more information about such approach at simoahava's blog. Hope it'll help someone =)